# How servlet can discover that button was pressed in jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have jsp page with many buttons. When I pressed some button it handle in servlet, but how I can identify that button was pressed? I do that:

```
private String getPressedBtn(HttpServletRequest request){
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
    String pressBtn = "";
    if(parameterNames.hasMoreElements()){
        pressBtn = parameterNames.nextElement();
    }
    return pressBtn;
}
```

But I think that it's very bad way. Wich way is properly?

Comment: Why don't you just submit a form to that `Servlet` when the button is pressed?

Comment: Sry but I dont understand what does it means...

Comment: You know the button was clicked because you submit the form to that `Servlet` only when it is clicked...

Comment: Or use a hidden input to pass a value that says whether the button was clicked or not.

Comment: oh...I can't do taht , is requirement of this task

Comment: Your way is "good enough", since you've localized the `value` of the buttons and can't use the same `name` for them all.  It's not the prettiest way, but it's not a "very bad way".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get pressed button in servlet, there is better way to do it:
At first, use input tag for buttons, define common name attribute for buttons and specific value for each button.

Example:

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="button1" />
<input type="button" name="button" value="button2" />
...
```

Then in servlet you can get it by this way:

```
private String getPressedBtn(HttpServletRequest request){
    return request.getParameter("button");
}
```

Comment: but value in button localized..

Comment: What does it means "localized"?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<fmt:message key="keyRegistration"/>" class="register" />

Comment: So, do you expect that you will receive not localized button value?

Answer (score 0):

In each button, you put a link inside, all link have the same request address, but differrent button name in parameters.

Comment: u wont say that I must use href? I do that in differ case...In that case I msut use button..

Comment: Use onClick="location.href='link'" in the button